# How to unblock file via WindowsPowerShell?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am using windows Vista buissnes 32 bit.
When I try to execute command :

```
dir *.* -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

I am getting : The term 'Unblock-File' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, fun..
I am running 2.0 version of powershell
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: as gronostaj told, its not supported. But AFAIK the information is stored in an alternate datastream. So doing this will discard **all** alternate datastreams: "type MyFile.exe > MyFileWithoutADS.exe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's [article on `Unblock-File`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849924.aspx) states that:

> This cmdlet is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

PowerShell 3.0 is not available for Vista, so you're out of luck.